# Facebook Comments Plugin styling

Tags: comments, facebook-ui

I added the facebook comments plugin in my site, I wanted to add styling to the plugin according to my site style. The below code which I added in mysite.

```
<fb:comments href="<url>" num_posts="2" width="500"></fb:comments>
```

Please suggest me how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible to style in a custom form. This is because the comments are loaded within an iframe.

Facebook offers two color schemes for the plugins, a light and dark theme, but other than these that is all that is possible using fb:comments

```
<fb:comments href="<url>" num_posts="2" width="500" colorscheme="dark"></fb:comments>
```

or

```
<fb:comments href="<url>" num_posts="2" width="500" colorscheme="light"></fb:comments>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not enough styling but if you are conscious about the responsiveness then you can use data-width="100%" instead of data-width="500" or '600'